# How to match String only contain Alphanumeric characters, a dash and an underscore using Regex

Tags: java, regex

All:

What I want to do is using Regex to match a string which only allow [A-Za-z0-9_-] and the format should be:

Started with only [A-Za-z0-9], and followed by [A-Za-z0-9_-]. There could be [_-] in the middle, but if there is any, it is only allowed once(both _ and - can exist, but each one only has one chance), and ended with [A-Za-z0-9].

I only know how to match Alphanumeric characters, a dash and an underscore, but have no idea how to limit their occurrence time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(-[^-]*-|_[^_]*_))[A-Za-z0-9][\w-]*[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR0bA3/1)

#### Explanation:

- `^` - Line start
- `(?!.*(-[^-]*-|_[^_]*_))` - Negative lookahead which means fail the match if there are 2 underscore or 2 hyphens ahead
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` - Match 1 alphanumeric character
- `[\w-]*` - Match 0 or more of `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` characters
- `$` - Match line end

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty new to RE, could you give me a little explanation about this? I do not quite understand about this

Comment: I have added explanation in answer

Comment: Thanks, I open that Regex demo: But I wonder why the " foo-bar_baz" does not match, It is supposed to match

Comment: Actually `foo-bar_baz` does match. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR0bA3/2) With multiple inputs `[^-]*` matches `\n` also.

Comment: Voted! This is amazing, but could you give me a little more detail how that mystery Negative lookahead part works? I guess that should be my first thing to figure out.

Comment: [Read more about lookaheads here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and let me know anything is not clear.

Comment: I read that document, it seems this lookahead is matching a position in a string. But I still want to be clear about some fundamental concept about how lookahead work? I wonder when RE engine matches my string with "^(?!.*(-[^-]*-|_[^_]*_))", if there is no  matching, the position will be the end of string, and if it will return a true, then other matching happens. Otherwise, if it find duplicated -/_ pattern, it will return false. Then what happen? The engine did not process other match?